# Is the "Tomorrow" series of John Marsden based on real events?

Tags: john-marsden, the-tomorrow-series

I have read the *Tomorrow* series of John Marsden multiple times and the book says it is based on real places (as mentioned in the first book *Tomorrow when the war began* chapter *"Author's note"*) and interviewed multiple persons (mentioned in the chapter *"Acknowledgements"*) about the story. But the author did not give more information. So I assume the books are based on real events. Is this correct?

When I did some research I did not find any information about the real events. Australia was not at war during the time period it happened (on its own land).

So I was wondering: did the real events take place in Australia, and who were the invaders?

Spoiler alert: the country was split up between them and the invaders (which to my knowledge did not happen with Australia).

I have read the books a few years back and this is a question that I am unable to let go of.

The first time I read the books, it was the Dutch version and I remember somme things I am unable to find in the English version (due to translation, due to false memories, or understanding things incorrectly, or a combination), such as the fact that the interviewed people were the survivors of the story but with different names.

Comment: You write, "the book says it is based on real places and interviewed multiple persons about the story". Where does it say that?

Comment: The part of real places in the Author's Note (book one), The persons are mentioned in "Acknowledgements", I can not find where (book 1-4) it is tated but I remember somehware it is stated that the events are base of real events and the information is gather from somme of the caracters in the book (I is plosible I misunderstood it and/or are changed lost in translation to Dutch).

Comment: It would be great if you could include the specific pointers to parts of the text back into the original question.

Comment: Also, welcome to LitSE, thanks for coming by.

Comment: [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_series) and other sources make it clear how the book was written, by Marsden imagining what would happen if Australia was invaded. If you read up on Australian history at all it should be obvious it didn't happen. It's based on fictional events set in real places, just as if I wrote a story set in London or Amsterdam that didn't actually happen, I might still include real locations and conduct research into any real-world elements (whether weapons, military tactics, or what teenagers like to do).